# Mouse events on NSView with ellipse as content

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I create a subclass of NSView that draw a red filled circle and i'd like to intercept mouse click that came into Red Circle only and not in transparent pixels. 
I think that i have to work with `hitTest:` function, but i'm not sure this's the right way.

(My view has `AcceptFirstMouse` and `MouseDown` implementation, `isOpaque` return NO.)

What can i do to obtain this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `hitTest:withEvent:` won't help you in this case, since the point will pass this test if it is **anywhere** inside the view's frame.
Maybe (quite) simple calculations will do what you want, assuming you at least know the circle's center position (maybe just the same as the view one), and the radius of your circle. The problem is now determining if the distance between the circle's center and your point is less than the radius.

Then you can easily write a function, for instance :

```
+(BOOL)ispoint:(CGPoint)aPoint inCircleWithCenter:(CGPoint)aCenterPoint
        radius:(CGFloat)aRadius {
    CGFloat squareDistance = (aCenter.x - aPoint.x) * (aCenter.x - aPoint.x) +
                             (aCenter.y - aPoint.y) * (aCenter.y - aPoint.y);
    return squareDistance <= aRadius * aRadius;
}
```

We can actually discuss the `<=`, which could just `<`... This is a **class method** you can equip your custom subclass with. Or write a function :

```
BOOL CGPointInCircle(CGPoint aPoint, CGPoint aCenter, CGFloat aRadius) {
    CGFloat squareDistance = (aCenter.x - aPoint.x) * (aCenter.x - aPoint.x) +
                             (aCenter.y - aPoint.y) * (aCenter.y - aPoint.y);
    return squareDistance <= aRadius * aRadius;
}
```

Comment: Since each view has its own circle whose rect must be known, why not make this an instance method?

Comment: @Josh Caswell - That's right, I agree with you. I think having a class method is interesting too, as it could be available without instanciating.

Comment: @Vince it could just be a function, if you aren't interested in the state of the object.

Comment: @Grady Player - Ok you convinced me ;) Am I making incorrect design writing a class method ?

Comment: @Grady Player - I mean does writing a class method make sense at all ?

Comment: the distance can be calculated with the hypot(x, y) function as well. So in your example you could rewrite it as: distance = hypot (aCenter.x - aPoint.x, aCenter.y - aPoint.y); return distance <= aRadius;

Comment: @vince sure you could write it as a class method. Nothing wrong with that. a function has a slight performance advantage.

Comment: Perfect, than i must call this function inside `MouseDown` implementation and go on it only in if `isPoint:` return true. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `hitTest:` is what you want. Assuming you're using an NSBezierPath to draw the circle, just implement `hitTest:` as `[path containsPoint:[self convertPoint:testPoint fromView:[self superview]]] ? self : nil`.